# fill jquery tabs header with information from database

Tags: php, jquery, tabs

I have the structure of a Tab component, but I will like that the head of each tab is the name of a person that is in the database stored.

For example, normally this is a tabs structure

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3">3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panels">
  <div id="tab-1">
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But instead of Tab 1,2 and 3 as head text for each tab, I will like to have Marc, Josef, Luis and these are name from the DB. This also includes that everytime that a person is added I will have a new tab. Has anybody a idea how I can do this?

I tryed to call the result of the PHP query in the text of the head, but was not working
**********EDITED WITH CODE******************

```
 <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect(/*DAta connectionns*/);
    if (!$connection)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("", $connection);


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM People");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $r = $row["name"];


 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1"><?php $r ?></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panels">
     </div>
    </div>
        }
    ?>
```

I know that there is something wrong, but I can not see

Comment: Show your (assumed ajax?) attempt that did not work...

Comment: Do you realize that if you have a few dozen of users you will have a lot of tabs? Which is the reason you would do that? Please explain it so we could try to find a better solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a JavaScript Object (from your ajax?) you can do:

```
var mytabs = [{
  name: "Marc"
}, {
  name: "Josef"
}, {
  name: "Luis"
}];
$('#tabs').tabs();
$.each(mytabs, function(indexInArray, myobj) {
  $('#tabs').find('li> a').eq(indexInArray).text(myobj.name);
});
```

Here is a fiddle you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/p4mzy3hb/

Comment: Hi Mark,thx for your answer. I was not using JSON or ajax but you brought me to this idea and the example make me change my mind.